# Apache Ranger Api not returning data

Tags: api, apache-ranger

I'm trying to access user info via ranger API, and I stumbled upon a strange issue:

When I access `/xusers/users/userName/{userName}` I don't get the expected JSON, like in this URL: `https://ranger.apache.org/apidocs/resource_XUserREST.html`

If I have a username that's called `sUsername` and I try `/xusers/users/userName/Username` (without `s`), I get the entire JSON **even if the user isn't in any group!**

If I enter `/xusers/users/userName/sUsername` I get the entire JSON **except the `groupIdList` and `groupNameList`**. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue, I can see the same behaviour. If the requirement is to get the **groupIdList** and **groupNameList**, then we have to use following api:-

```
/service/xusers/users/{id}
```

I understand, each time you have to get the id of the user but with the help of `jq` utility, we can map the names to id.

```
cat user.json | jq '.vXUsers[] | "\(.id) \(.name)"'
```

In this case **user.json** would be the file that has all the group and user information.

Following api should help generating **user.json**:-

```
curl -k  -u admin:admin -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET https://ranger_host:6182/service/xusers/users -o user.txt
```